# Transformers pipeline inference for ever gradually fill ram

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, huggingface-transformers, ram

I have trained a BERT model and using it for inference on a windows server on CPU. for the incoming data I apply pipeline on a batch of text and repeat it forever in a `while` loop.

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_PATH)
saved_model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_PATH, config=config)
pipe = pipeline('text-classification', model=saved_model, tokenizer=tokenizer, config=config)

while True:
    #Reading recent posts (a list of strings)
    texts = last_posts_without_sentiments()
    sents = pipe(texts)
```

the problem is that it turns out that in each loop the amount of used memory increase a bit and in long run it fills up my memory. I added the `collect` to the `while` but no improvement occurred.

```
while True:
    #Reading recent posts (a list of strings)
    texts = last_posts_without_sentiments()
    sents = pipe(texts) 
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: This is too little code, we cannot reproduce the problem with your current code.